# Trying to parse a webpage

Tags: php

What im trying to do is get this page 
http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Helix+Pelegando
and get all deaths from this page and im stuck
anybody know what im doing wrong?

EDIT-
the problem is that im not getting any results at all

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Helix+Pelegando');
        $domd = new domDocument;
        $domx = new DOMXPath($domd);

        $domd->loadHTML($html);

        $worlds = $domx->query("//*b[text() = 'Character Deaths']/ancestor::table[1]//tr[position() > 1]");  
            $deaths = array();

        foreach ($worlds as $row) {
            $date = $row->firstChild->nodeValue;
            $text = $row->lastChild->nodeValue;

            preg_match("/Died at Level (\\d+) by (.+)\\./", $text, $matches);
            $deaths[] = array(
                "date"      =>  DateTime::createFromFormat("M d Y, H:i:s T", $date),
                "level"     =>  $matches[1],
                "reason"    =>  $matches[2],
            );
        }
```

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is.  Are you getting an error?  Are you getting incorrect results?  We don't know what you're trying to fix.

Comment: what are u trying to accomplish ??

Comment: im trying to get the list of deaths in this page http://www.tibia.com/community/?subtopic=characters&name=Helix+Pelegando and parse it into an array